# (Rcpp)armadillos abs() function outputs false values when used with c++ double while std::abs works

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, armadillo, rcpparmadillo

Consider this R function:

```
r_abs <- function(x,y,z){
    2 * abs((x >= y) - z)
}
```

And those 2 RcppArmadillo equivalents:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppProgress)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <string>
#include <progress.hpp>
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double arma_abs(const double &x, const double &y, const double &z)
{
    return 2 * abs((x >= y) - z);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double std_abs(const double &x, const double &y, const double &z)
{
    return 2 * std::abs((x >= y) - z);
}
```

Now here is the problem:

```
sourceCpp(".test/test.cpp")

x <- 1
y <- 2
z <- 0.5

r_abs(x,y,z)
[1] 1
arma_abs(x, y, z)
[1] 0
std_abs(x, y, z)
[1] 1
```

Why does arma_abs() output 0 here? The problem only occurs for `-1 < z < 1`.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a tricky and somewhat tedious issue with C and C++ *partially fixed* by the corred `std::abs()` added more recently.

If you're on a Unix system try `man 3 abs`.  Your use of the (unqualified) `abs()` is equivalent to `::abs()` and it gets `int abs(int)` from `stdlib.h`.

And the cast to `int` makes the argument -0.5 truncate to zero which times two is still zero.  In short, `arma` has nothing to do with this. (And Armadillo generally only has functions for its vector, matrix, cube, ... types and not atomic C/C++ types like `double`).

For completeness, my version of your code with the R part embedded below. I removed the unused references RcppProgress.

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

//using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double arma_abs(const double &x, const double &y, const double &z) {
  auto val = (x >= y) - z;
  Rcpp::Rcout << "val " << val << std::endl;
  Rcpp::Rcout << "int(val) " << int(val) << std::endl;
  return 2 * ::abs((x >= y) - z);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double std_abs(const double &x, const double &y, const double &z) {
    return 2 * std::abs((x >= y) - z);
}

/*** R

r_abs <- function(x,y,z){
    2 * abs((x >= y) - z)
}

x <- 1
y <- 2
z <- 0.5

r_abs(x,y,z)           # 1
arma_abs(x, y, z)      # 0
std_abs(x, y, z)       # 1
*/
```

*Edit:* Typo corrected. Above I wrote `std::fabs()` when I meant `std::abs()`.  `fabs()` is what we always had to use to avoid the very issue of a cast to `int` seen here.